# Custom HTML Form Element with Shadow DOM gives blank html page

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

The code is from this page https://usefulangle.com/post/362/custom-elements
It builds a custom html form element with shadow DOM.

But, when I open it in a browser, it's blank.
[image]

I opened the code in "Inspect" and saw this error.

[image]

```js
class InputPlusMinus extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    let template = document.querySelector('#input-plus-minus-template').content;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));

    let add_button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#add");
    let subtract_button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#subtract");
    let count_textbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#count");

    this.setAttribute('value', '1');

    add_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let current = parseInt(count_textbox.value, 10);
      count_textbox.value = current + 1;
      this.setAttribute('value', count_textbox.value);
    });

    subtract_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let current = parseInt(count_textbox.value, 10);
      if (current > 1) {
        count_textbox.value = current - 1;
        this.setAttribute('value', count_textbox.value);
      }
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('input-plus-minus', InputPlusMinus);
```

```html
<template id="input-plus-minus-template">
        <style>
        button {
            width: 25%;
            /* other CSS */
        }
    
        input {
            width: 50%;
            /* other CSS */
        }
        </style>
        <div id="container">
            <button id="subtract">-</button>
            <input type="text" id="count" value="1" readonly />
            <button id="add">+</button>
        </div>
    </template>


<!-- custom element being used -->
<input-plus-minus id="sample"></input-plus-minus>
```

Comment: What browser and version?

Comment: Microsoft Edge Version 95.0.1020.53 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: @mplungjan  When I run the edited code snippet here, it shows me the result. But, when I copy the code to .html file and open it in a browser, it just shows the text

Comment: class InputPlusMinus extends HTMLElement { constructor() { super(); let template = document.querySelector('#input-pl

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836886/failed-to-construct-customelement-error-when-javascript-file-is-placed-in-head

Comment: @ Gabriele Petrioli
 That worked. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I modified the code and it works now. Thank You so much!!

```js
class InputPlusMinus extends HTMLElement {

  connectedCallback() {
    let template = document.querySelector('#input-plus-minus-template').content;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));

    let add_button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#add");
    let subtract_button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#subtract");
    let count_textbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#count");

    this.setAttribute('value', '1');

    add_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let current = parseInt(count_textbox.value, 10);
      count_textbox.value = current + 1;
      this.setAttribute('value', count_textbox.value);
    });

    subtract_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let current = parseInt(count_textbox.value, 10);
      if (current > 1) {
        count_textbox.value = current - 1;
        this.setAttribute('value', count_textbox.value);
      }
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('input-plus-minus', InputPlusMinus);
```

```html
<template id="input-plus-minus-template">
            <style>
            button {
                width: 25%;
                /* other CSS */
            }
        
            input {
                width: 50%;
                /* other CSS */
            }
            </style>
            <div id="container">
                <button id="subtract">-</button>
                <input type="text" id="count" value="1" readonly />
                <button id="add">+</button>
            </div>
        </template>


<!-- custom element being used -->
<input-plus-minus id="sample"></input-plus-minus>
```